# How to get variable from subprocess.call in Python?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, call, stdout

I'm trying to count the number of lines that start with ">" using grep and then store that value as a `Python` integer object [`int`].  I'm running the command with `subprocess` using the `call` method.

```
In [8]: x = subprocess.call(f"grep -c '^>' {path}", shell=True)
4626

In [9]: x
Out[9]: 0
```

It's going to `stdout` but I want it to go into the variable `x`.

Comment: This code has serious security vulnerabilities. Keep in mind that `$(rm -rf ~)` is completely legal as part of a filename; so is `; rm /etc/passwd`.

Comment: It'd be much safer to use `subprocess.call(['grep', '-c', '^>', '--', path])`, or, barring that, `subprocess.call(['''grep -c '^>' -- "$1"''', '_', path], shell=True)`.

Comment: See the "warning" section in red in the documentation at https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments for more discussion.

Comment: So much dread looking at this line: `rm -rf ~`

Comment: @O.rka: You can also just do this within Python: `with open(filename, 'rb') as handle: total = sum(line.startswith('>') for line in handle)`.

Comment: Thanks @Blender I think the `bash` way is faster and I'm trying to speed it up since I'm working with 5GB text files.  I just recently started using `subprocess`

Comment: Could well be -- `grep` is heavily optimized. That said, if you're going to be doing this repeatedly, getting your data into an indexed format so this stops being an O(n) operation is in your interest. (If the lines are sorted, for instance, then it's a bisect operation to find either the start or the end of the section that starts with `>`; that gives you the number of *bytes* between those two regions in amortized constant time).

Comment: `x = int(subprocess.run(['grep', '-c', '^>', "--", path], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.strip())`

Comment: ...once you know the byte offsets, whether it requires an O(n) scan through that section to count number of *lines* is a question of whether the line length is constant, or if there's a line number in the data format -- if the latter, then it could just be a matter of subtraction, and there you are.

Comment: (point I'm making being that slow operations can generally be avoided if your data structures are well-considered).

Comment: @O.rka: `grep` takes twice as long for me for a 2.5GB file, regardless of the number of lines starting with `>`. You may want to test it out before committing to a particular solution due to performance. You can shrink the performance gap by using `LC_ALL=C grep ...`.